# Sending a HEAD request results in CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching

Tags: security, http, dns, http-headers, ioexception

I'm sending a HEAD request to a video file URL in an effort to efficiently check for the url's availability, as well as to grab the size of the video file without actually downloading it (via Content-Length).

There certain instances where I'm getting:

```
IOException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching gcdn.2mdn.net found
```

I've searched around SO, and there are solutions regarding certificate generation, but is that what my fix would be too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the HTTPs certificate of the video URL sends you to a different DNS name when performing HEAD?

Anyway note that if the server does not explicitly implements HEAD, it could do nothing or it could even do whatever he does to retrieve the video with a GET (not sending you the body, that's true, but the server will load the video twice). But as HEAD is not a very common verb, rely on it could be a bad choice, as long as the video URL does not explicitly state so.